# How to get the service in event viewer

Tags: .net, windows-services

I created one windows service. After installing the service, i started service. but i didnt get the event log for my service.

I used the following code.

```
public partial class Service1 : ServiceBase
{
    public Service1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.ServiceName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("ServiceName");
        string sourceName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Source"];
        string logName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Log"];
        if (!System.Diagnostics.EventLog.SourceExists(sourceName))
            System.Diagnostics.EventLog.CreateEventSource(sourceName, logName);
        eventLog.Source = sourceName;
        eventLog.Log = logName;

    }

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        eventLog.WriteEntry("Service Starting...");
    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        eventLog.WriteEntry("Service Stopped...");
    }
}
```

I check this in event viewwe, i didnt get my service name.

How to get this.

Thanks,
Pooja

Answer (score 0):

The most likely reason for this is that the service user doesn't have enough authority to create event sources.

You will need to add try/catch handlers to the constructor to determine if this is the case.

You can also try running the service as a local administrator user, which should cause the event source to be created.

Because of this reason, we always create our event sources during installation and require an admin user to run the installation.

Another option, which we use, is to gracefully degrade to using the Application event log in the event we encounter a security exception creating our event source:

```
    try {
        if (!System.Diagnostics.EventLog.SourceExists(sourceName))
            System.Diagnostics.EventLog.CreateEventSource(sourceName, logName);
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        sourceName = "Application";
    }
    eventLog.Source = sourceName;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. How to check if i have a admin authority , how to get this authotity.

Comment: Take a look at this MSDN documentation. The answer varies depending on your operating system: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2awhba7a.aspx